# How do you remove the tagName in a component in ember 2.4?

Tags: ember.js, components, tagname

I am trying to add a component without a tagName but I cannot use

tagName = ''

because it causes an error in ember 2.4.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ember 2.4 too. The following code works and removes the surrounding tag:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: ''
});
```

Comment: no it only gives an error if you use `this.$()` to access the dom element (which does not exist with `tagName: ''`)